# dice rolls: error when replicating function

Tags: r

I want to make program that roll dice until some conescutive result. First I write loop:

```
rolls <- 0
die1 <- 0
die2 <- 0
while(!(die1 == 5 & die2 == 3)) {
  die1 <- sample(1:6, 1)
  die2 <- sample(1:6, 1)
  rolls <- rolls + 1
}
print(rolls)
```

Now I want to make function of this loop and repeat function 100 times:

```
rolls <- 0 

dice <- function(die1 = a, die2 = b){

while(!(die1 == a & die2 == b)) {
  die1 <- sample(1:6, 1)
  die2 <- sample(1:6, 1)
  rolls <- rolls + 1


return(rolls)
}}

r1 = replicate(100,dice(5,3))
r2 = replicate(100,dice(6,6))
```

But I gets error `Error in die1 == a & die2 == b : non-conformable arrays`

Why this error? How I can fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up your function parameters and return value incorrectly. Leave the names off the parameters and move the `return()` to outside the loop

```
dice <- function(a, b){
  die1 <- 0
  die2 <- 0
  rolls <- 0 
  while(!(die1 == a & die2 == b)) {
    die1 <- sample(1:6, 1)
    die2 <- sample(1:6, 1)
    rolls <- rolls + 1
  }
  return(rolls)
}
r1 = replicate(100,dice(5,3))
r2 = replicate(100,dice(6,6))
```

Comment: thx! just a question - i want to confirm how this function is counting. for ex, suppose I want 4,6

Comment: roll 1: 1,4 .. roll2 : 6,5 .... roll 3: 4,6

Comment: the number of rolls until 4,6 was : 3 rolls

Comment: I dont want it to say 2 rolls (use last number from previous roll and combine it with first number from next roll)

Comment: It would say 3 rolls.

Comment: Thx you mrflick! do you know how i can modify ur code to roll "pair of dice"?